# Move toolbar in wysiwyg text editors Aloha, TinyCME, CKEditor

Tags: tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg, toolbar, aloha-editor

In the three editors "Aloha", "TinyMCE" and "CKEditor", i am trying to separate the text-field and the toolbar, and keep the toolbar visible at all times.

TinyMCE, Using

```
inline: true,
fixed_toolbar_container: "div#mytoolbar",
```

i have been able to do the separation, but the toolbar hides when the text-field is out of focus.

Aloha and CKEditor i don't have anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of CKEditor, check out the [Sharedspace plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) and [config.sharedSpaces](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-sharedSpaces) option. There's also a [sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/sharedspace/sharedspace.html).

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'inline1', {
    extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
    removePlugins: 'floatingspace,resize',
    sharedSpaces: {
        top: 'top',
        bottom: 'bottom'
    }
} );
```